# In my Solr schema, what is the difference between tdouble and tdoubles?

Tags: solr, schema

There are a number of fields in Solr such as int and ints, what is the difference?

ints can hold multiple values?  Sounds to me like that is what 'multiValued' is. And I can't seem to find any documentation on field types ending with 's'.

Couple interesting related links:
https://prismoskills.appspot.com/lessons/Solr/Chapter_20_-_Field_types_-_schema.xml.jsp
https://github.com/alfallouji/TIKR/blob/master/conf/solr/managed-schema

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. A multiValued field can hold a list of values in a single field.

If you look at the definition of the two fields, they're identical, except that one (`ints`) is defined to keep a list of fields. If you have a single value in this field, it'll still be returned as a list (i.e. `[42]` instead of just `42`).

Comment: So multiValued vs ints Is it's the difference between using a single field vs multiple fields to store multiple values?  Not sure I understand the difference?

Comment: If you're using multiple fields, they'll have to have unique names. If you have a field that can have many values (for example a list of locations, a list of id's associated with a document, etc.), making the field multiValued makes more sense (so you can have `user_ids: [1, 4, 6, 10]` or for example `categories:["Hats", "Accessories", "Foo"]`). Having category_1, category_2, category_3 wouldn't be very flexible.